# How to insert if its a new data or update if it already exists

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-update, sql-insert

I was looking at this question/answer here: [Insert into a MySQL table or update if exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205181/insert-into-a-mysql-table-or-update-if-exists) but I am confused. I have this table (customers):

```
cus_id | driver_id | name   | age
1      | 1234      | Bob    | 20
2      | 987       | James  | 21
3      | 5000      | Jane   | 23
```

SQL

```
CREATE TABLE customers(
cus_id int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
driver_id int(4) NOT NULL,
name varchar(32),
age int(3)
);
```

I always search via `driver_id`. `cus_id` is the primary key and `AUTO_INCREMENT`'s. And always update `name` and `age`.

So I would use the statement

```
INSERT INTO customers (driver_id, name, age) VALUES(1234, "Bobby", 21) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE    
name="Bobby", age=21
```

The issue is now, what is DUPLICATE KEY? I am not searching the duplicate via the `cus_id`. I and searching the duplicate my their `driver_id`.

So in the above statement, it would update the row with the `cus_id=1`, not insert a row because the `driver_id` `1234` already exists.

So the table would look like:

```
cus_id | driver_id | name   | age
1      | 1234      | Bobby  | 21
2      | 987       | James  | 21
3      | 5000      | Jane   | 23
```

Comment: create a unique index on driver_id or change the index to unique if there is one

Comment: @BerndBuffen Can you show me an example please

Comment: Incidentally, the number in parentheses following an int declaration is almost meaningless

Comment: @Strawberry Really? So I shouldn't put it? I'm just trying to save space and I know for a fact that I will never exceed `9999`

Comment: Yep, I'm not making it up. In that instance you would want SMALLINT. Although be aware that 'space' is very cheap.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your Sample:

**Create the Table**

```
MariaDB [bernd]> CREATE TABLE customers (
                   cus_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                   driver_id INT(11),
                   name VARCHAR(32),
                   age int(11)
                );
                Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

**Now insert the Data**

```
    MariaDB [bernd]> INSERT INTO customers (driver_id,name,age) VALUES
     (1234,'Bob',20),
     (987,'James',21),
     (5000,'Jane',23);
    Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.00 sec)
    Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

**Watch the Data**

```
MariaDB [bernd]> SELECT * FROM customers;
+--------+-----------+-------+------+
| cus_id | driver_id | name  | age  |
+--------+-----------+-------+------+
|      1 |      1234 | Bob   |   20 |
|      2 |       987 | James |   21 |
|      3 |      5000 | Jane  |   23 |
+--------+-----------+-------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**ADD the unique Key**

```
MariaDB [bernd]> ALTER TABLE customers ADD UNIQUE (driver_id);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

You can also add the Key directly with the *CREATE TABLE* Statement

**Insert a Record with a duplicate driver_id**

```
MariaDB [bernd]> INSERT INTO customers (driver_id, name, age) VALUES(1234, "Bobby", 21) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    -> name="Bobby", age=21;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

**Watch the changed Data**

```
MariaDB [bernd]> SELECT * FROM customers;
+--------+-----------+-------+------+
| cus_id | driver_id | name  | age  |
+--------+-----------+-------+------+
|      1 |      1234 | Bobby |   21 |
|      2 |       987 | James |   21 |
|      3 |      5000 | Jane  |   23 |
+--------+-----------+-------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: As @GordonLinoff mentioned, MySQL doesn't let you choose which key. So what is my solution to this problem? Because there is a very strong possibility that someone's `cus_id` and someones `driver_id` might be the same. So what is my solution. My main aim is to ensure that I don't have insert a duplicate person into my table and update a person if they already exist

Answer (score 0):

> The issue is now, what is DUPLICATE KEY?

Your table definition has only one key, `cus_id`.  And it is auto-incremented, so it can never be duplicated -- after all, the `insert` statement should be letting the database choose the next value.

If you want `driver_id` to be unique, you need a unique constraint or index on that column.  The easiest method is when you create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
    cus_id int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    driver_id int(4) NOT NULL UNIQUE
    name varchar(32),
    age int(3)
);
```

However, you can also add it after the fact as a unique constraint or index:

```
alter table customers add constraint unq_customers_driver_id unique(driver_id);
```

Or alternatively:

```
create unique index unq_customers_driver_id on customers(driver_id);
```

Unfortunately, MySQL does not let you "choose" which duplicated key gets processed.  *Any* duplicated key triggers the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` logic.

Comment: Well there is a very strong possibility that someone's `cus_id` and someones `driver_id` might be the same. So what is my solution. My main aim is to ensure that I don't have insert a duplicate person into my table and update a person if they already exist